# EntityFramework DB First Keyword not supported: 'port'

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, db-first

I want make model using db-first entity framwork.

so i enter the command like picture below.

but the error message shown as Keyword not supported: 'port'.

how do i fix this issue. thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the syntax is incorrect , here you don't need to add the keyword 'port' instead of that try using SERVER_NAME comma PORT_NUMBER like this . its worked for me !

"server=SERVER_NAME,PORT_NUMBER;user=USER_NAME;password=PASSWORD;database=DB_NAME"

Comment: thanks for your comment! i write the syntax as follow "caffold-DbContext "server=localhost,5432;user=postgres;password=691dlclf;database=AstDevManagement; TrustServerCertificate=True;Encrypt=false" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models2".

But, the another error has occurred. 
Error Number:64,State:0,Class:20
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake.  Sir, did you have seen this error before..?